# Chrome - toLocaleString() - Thousands separator is not working for Spanish

Tags: javascript, locale

In Chrome, when the locale is set in 'es' the thousands separator is not there.

[image]

If I use 4 digit number, there is not problem

Data Set:

```
(2500).toLocaleString('en')
"2,500"
(2500).toLocaleString('pt')
"2.500"
(2500).toLocaleString('es')
"2500"

(25000).toLocaleString('es')
"25.000"
```

Why is this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the CLDR, this is the intended behavior.
The "Minimum Grouping Digits" is 2, meaning that, only when a number has 2 digits before the other 3 digits, the thousand separator would appear.
Apparently, this was only applied to chrome, since other browsers are using the "old" specifications.

Check this https://st.unicode.org/cldr-apps/v#/es/Symbols/70ef5e0c9d323e01

A possible workaround I used FOR SPECIFIC CASES, is to set it to the German locale ("de") instead of Spanish:

(1000).toLocaleString("de")

"1.000"

Comment: Great hack! very usefull!

Comment: Using an incorrect locale defeats the purpose of using the toLocaleString function.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour is indeed the one mentioned in the accepted answer.

However, rather than using the workaround mentioned above which defeats the purpose of using the `toLocaleString()` function, I would suggest using the `useGrouping: true` parameter.

```
(1000).toLocaleString("es-ES", { useGrouping: true })
// expected output: '1.0000'
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat#usegrouping

Answer (score 1):

Note that using any Latin American Spanish locale will bypass the issue (and is a closer match to es-ES than using German).